# Is it possible to use more than 1.5 Gb of memory with an Azure Function App V2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I'm currently using v2 of Azure Function Apps.  I've set the environment to be 64 bit and am compiling to .Net Standard 2.0.  Host Json specifies version 2.

I'm reading in a .csv and it works fine for smaller files.  But when I read in a 180MB .csv into a List of string[] it's ballooning to over a GB on read and when I try to parse it, it's up over 2 GB but then throws the 'Out of Memory' Exception.  Even running on an app service plan with more than 3.5 GB hasn't solved the issue.

Edit: 
I'm using this:

```
Uri blobUri = AppendSasOnUri(blobName); _webClient = new WebClient(); 
Stream sourceStream = _webClient.OpenRead(blobUri); 
_reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream);
```

However, since It's a csv, I'm splitting out entire columns of data.  It's pretty hard to get away from this:

```
internal async Task<List<string[]>> ReadCsvAsync() { 
    while (!_reader.EndOfStream) { 
        string[] currentCsvRow = await ReadCsvRowAsync(); 
        _fullBlobCsv.Add(currentCsvRow); 
    } 
return _fullBlobCsv; }
```

Goal is to store json into blob when alls said and done.

Answer (score 0):

Try using stream (`StreamReader`) to read the input .csv file and process one line at a time.

I'm able to parse 300mb files on consumption plan with streams. My use-case may not be same but similar. Parse a large concatenated pdf file and separate it to 5000+ smaller files and store the separated files into blob container.  Below is my code for reference.

For your use case you may want to use `CloudAppendBlob` instead of `CloudBlockBlob` if you're pushing all parsed data into single blob.

```
public async static void ExtractSmallerFiles(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string fileDate, ILogger log)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(await myBlob.OpenReadAsync()))
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = null;
        var fileContents = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.StartsWith("%%MS_SKEY_0000_000_PDF:"))
            {
                var matches = Regex.Match(line, @"%%MS_SKEY_0000_000_PDF: A(\d+)_SMFL_B1234_D(\d{8})_A\d+_M(\d{15}) _N\d+");
                var smallFileDate = matches.Groups[2];
                var accountNumber = matches.Groups[3];
                var fileName = $"SmallerFiles/{smallFileDate}/{accountNumber}.pdf";
                blockBlob = myBlob.Container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            }
            fileContents.AppendLine(line);
            if (line.Equals("%%EOF"))
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Uploading {fileContents.Length} bytes to {blockBlob.Name}");
                await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(fileContents.ToString());
                fileContents = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            }
        }
        await myBlob.DeleteAsync();
        log.LogInformation("Extracted Smaller files");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this:  
Uri blobUri = AppendSasOnUri(blobName);
                _webClient = new WebClient();
                Stream sourceStream = _webClient.OpenRead(blobUri);
                _reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream);
However, since It's a csv, I'm splitting out entire columns of data.
internal async Task<List<string[]>> ReadCsvAsync()
        {
            while (!_reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] currentCsvRow = await ReadCsvRowAsync();
                _fullBlobCsv.Add(currentCsvRow);
            }
            return _fullBlobCsv;
        }